# Location data update in server continuously in Flutter app even it is terminated or killed

Tags: android, ios, flutter, location, background-service

I want to track user location continuously and update it to server. Also user can set alarm to start tracking. User can kill app or terminate it so how to run a background service to track continuous location and post it to server? Is it possible to achieve it in flutter without writing native code in both android and ios platform?

Comment: It's not possible to achieve it *in* native code. The user can always turn off their location permission for your app

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 thanks for your reply. If user doesn't remove permission then it is possible to achieve in flutter or ios?

Comment: You can use significant location change monitoring on iOS which will relaunch your app if iOS terminates it, but I am pretty sure if the user kills it then it won't be relaunched.

Comment: Solve :  you can use  "flutter background geolocation" plugin it work even app is terminated

Comment: @VishwajeetSinghShekhawat it will work for DEBUG builds. It will not work with RELEASE builds without purchasing a license.

Answer (score 0):

You are right !! You can also go with flutter background service plugin and do some customization then maybe it's work